# if and else part not working in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried the if else statement in jquery but it is not working.here is my code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".checkboxes").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".Select").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).next(".checkboxes").slideToggle(500);
            if ($(".select").text() == "+") {
                alert('hi');
                $(".select").html() == "-"
            }
            else {
                $(".select").text() == "+";
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try `$(this).text()` instead of `$(".select").text()`

Comment: Please post relevant HTML of your elements

Comment: @soul i think semicolon is not neccessary in jquery

Comment: @RohitArora yup!!! but sometimes i might not work too

Comment: `==` conditional operators should be used as conditions, it is not an assignment operator : in `$(".select").text() == "+";`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a typo.. Put capital "S" instead of "s" as in your click event.

try below code :-

```
if ($(".Select").text() == "+") {
                alert('hi');
                $(".Select").html("-");
            }
            else {
                $(".Select").text() == "+";
            }
```

or simply use $(this) as below:-

```
 if ($(this).text().trim() == "+") {
            $(this).html("-");
        } else {
            $(this).text("+");
        }
```

Comment: now in your second edit, if the semicolon was necessary...why didn't you put it in?

Comment: when did i say semicolon is necessary @Manoz? read answer again

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a function call. Your code should throw an error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".checkboxes").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".Select").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".checkboxes").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).text(function (i, txt) {
            return txt.trim() == '+' ? '-' : '+'
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @RohitArora Ops code is `$(".select").html() == "-"` which is wrong... in the fiddle it is `$(".Select").html("-");` so that is fine

Comment: The previous answer also was correct... it was using the same `if..else` used by the OP but the bugs was fixed... by using `.html('+')`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbv6f26o/2/)
You should change your code to this while assigning it is `$(".Select").html("-");`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".checkboxes").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".Select").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).next(".checkboxes").slideToggle(500);
            if ($(".Select").text() == "+") {
                alert('hi');
                $(".Select").html("-");
            }
            else {
                $(".Select").text("+");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using two different classes `.Select` and `.select`. I think problem lies here. And second thing, it should be `html('-')` not `html() == '-'` because it is a logical/conditional statement and it will return a boolean. It is not an assignment statement. So your code should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".checkboxes").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".select").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next(".checkboxes").slideToggle(500);
        if ($(".select").text() == "+") {
            alert('hi');
            $(".select").html("-");
        }
        else {
            $(".select").text("+");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I suppose that correct class is `select` as you have used it more than `Select`.